# com.apple.mdworker.shared .... Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by mds[91]

Tags: macos-highsierra, spotlight

I’ve noticed a lot of similar system log entries as follow

**com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[622]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by mds[91]**

and also

**com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.single.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[1536]): Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9 sent by mds[91]**

Googling revealed that they are related to the Spotlight indexing.
I have disabled the indexing services completely via `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist` command but it seems to have no effect and logs still persist.

Is it something I should be concerned with?
(running macos high sierra with Macos Server)